# Normalize Semi-Structured JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, normalize

I have been trying to normalize a JSON file to succesfully convert it to a CSV later, but i just cant get to work.

Im trying normalize it with pandas pd.json_normalize but it seems to be a very nested JSON.

This is the json structure:

```json
    {
            "documentReport": {
                "documentId": "62f0f78a5e1428137492451c",
                "flowName": "sdsf",
                "flowStateName": "sent",
                "userName": "20304050607",
                "shortUrl": "vHppw8dm",
                "uploadDateUtc": "08/08/2022 08:46:18",
                "appId": "tucarpeta.com",
                "claro": {
                    "ctl_Id": "15836272",
                    "numberSds": "00441426TAE",
                    "numberOT": "12047839",
                    "entity": "193811",
                    "entityType": "432",
                    "channel": "1",
                    "presencial": 1,
                    "customer": {
                        "documentNumber": "23763407",
                        "name": "PAULA RAQUEL",
                        "lastName": "VELASQUEZ",
                        "cuit": null,
                        "sex": "F",
                        "email": "REFUGIOGABINETE@GMAIL.COM"
                    }
                }
            },
            "claroEventKpiReportModel": {
                "deviceData": {
                    "operativeSystem": "Android 10 undefined",
                    "model": "SAMSUNG SM-J400M",
                    "device": "mobile",
                    "browser": "Samsung Internet for Android"
                },
                "eventData": {
                    "eventDateUtc": "08/08/2022 08:49:50",
                    "eventName": "IDOC_DOCUMENT_OPENED_BY_AVA",
                    "userName": "system"
                },
                "result": "Ok"
            }
        }
```

and so it goes on with the next record.

The output i need is the following:

| documentId | flowName | flowStateName | userName | uploadDateUtc | numberSds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 62f0f78a5e1428137492451c | sdsf | sent | 20304050607 | 08/08/2022 08:46:18 | 00441426TAE |

And so with other records.

Can anyone help me how to use json_normalize to do so? Or how to get it done anyway.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After converting literal `null` value that is not a string to `np.nan`, use

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict).T
```

Answer (score 0):

`pd.json_normalize` can't parse every JSON schema out there. You can preprocess the data before turning it to a data frame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([{
    **{
        key: record["documentReport"][key]
        for key in ["documentId", "flowName", "flowStateName", "userName", "uploadDateUtc"]
    },
    "numberSds": record["documentReport"]["claro"]["numberSds"]
} for record in json_array])
```

Comment: Getting "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" error. I have already got this error trying other ways to parse the json.
The code im running:
`pd.read_json('jsonpath.json')
with open('jsonpath.json','r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

##stack answer
df = pd.DataFrame([{
    **{
        key: record["documentReport"][key]
        for key in ["documentId", "flowName", "flowStateName", "userName", "uploadDateUtc"]
    },
    "numberSds": record["documentReport"]["claro"]["numberSds"]
} for record in json_array])` json_array would be "data" in my case?

Comment: Yes. It is equivalent to your `data`. What does `type(data)` return? I assumed it was a list.